# Unterminated Literal String on function input

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have written a function which its input should have line-feeds in it:

```js
function goh(textt) {
    textt = textt.split('\n');
    for(i=0; i<textt.length; i++) {
        textt[i] = i+'='+textt[i]
    }
    return textt.join('\n');
}
```

which for example I want to call it in this way:

```
goh("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=");
```

but it gives me this error in the firefox's console. (BTW I have read all the questions asked about this before ...)

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

How can I fix this problem?

## EDIT:

Please everyone listen. I knew what are you talking here. in that case I would add the `\n` myself xD. **I want the script does this for me**
I want to pass the **RAW** Input.

Comment: The error is generated because you cannot break strings with newlines like that.

Comment: Take a look at this question to get more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Why not just pass an array instead, it makes no sense to pass in a string to that function

Comment: @adeneo I cant pass arrays... in that case it is not automation .. Im doing sth not?

Comment: Why not, if you can add `\n` to the string, you can surely push each string to an array instead, and you're creating an array by splitting in the function anyway.

Comment: In regards to your edit, if you receive a string with newlines this isn't an issue, the error message clearly states that you have a **string literal**, or in other words a string you literally wrote in javascript with invalid newlines.

Comment: @adeneo no no no! consider I want to pass a raw input. __I dont want to do anything to it and it has `\n` in it.__

Comment: And that's not an issue, strings containing newlines are fine. It's when you ***type literal strings*** with actual CR/LF ***in your javascript*** that you have an issue.

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean invalid .. also I tried to copy and paste the text to notepad++ and back to the console which didnt solve the problem .. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding :

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal How can I fix this problem?

you should use backslash :

```
goh("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=");
```

if you want to send pure linebreaks use `\n` as @amit answered.

Comment: Would this not effectively escape the newline characters in the string, which are expected in the OP's function...?

Comment: This just allow multiline strings, doesn't preserve the newline though `"\
".length // 0` -.- replace space with newline and run...

Comment: @dev-null regarding the error and his question actually about the error , a backslash would solve it

Comment: @RoyiNamir After your 5th edit you finally manage to answer a part of OPs question, but it doesn't really help hem though, because now OP will sit and wonder why the split doesn't work.

Comment: @dev-null Yes I've edited ( you make it sound bad) becuase wanted to answer for his concrete question.

Comment: @all I cant no no no I cant! I want the script do this for me, I just want to pass the raw input ..... not a good answer.

Comment: @TechLife What is the raw input ?  with \n or without ? you **can't** pass rawinput with linebreaks without `\\`

Comment: @RoyiNamir The raw input is in the question (in the function call - please read the question!) so you mean that this cant be done with javascript? is it a limitation?

Comment: @TechLife  yes. you can't do it with JS. you cannot pass this multiline (not ended with backslash nor \n )statement to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\n`. It acts the same.

```
goh("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v="); // many more
```

From your comment

> no no no I cant! I want the script do this for me, I just want to pass
>   the raw input ..... not a good answer.

You must use an array and push the "raw input" and join them.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("raw data");
arr.push("raw data");
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    console.log(arr[i], "There's no need of split");
```

Comment: no no no I cant! I want the script do this for me, I just want to pass the raw input ..... not a good answer.

Comment: @TechLife that's the best, I can do.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't allow multiline strings, you can however use `\n` which will give you a newline in the string:

```
var a = "a\nb\nc";

console.log(a); // will give you:
"a
b
c"
```

If you think one line will be to cluttered, you can always use string concatenation:

```
var a = "a\n" + 
  "b\n" + 
  "c";

// using String.prototype.concat    
var a = "a\n".concat(
  "b\n",
  "c\n"
);

// Using Array.prototype.join
var a = ["a", "b", "c"].join('\n');
```

And now my question is: Why don't you send in an array and forget about the hassle with splitting, joining etc?

Comment: @TechLife This `\n` and a newline is 100% the same, but when writing strings in JS you cannot simply write a newline, you will need to use `\n`.

Comment: @TechLife Can you stop with this "not a good answer" thing?  your approach of solving things is not a good one also. you cannot use multiline without slash( Im repeating this for the third time here  , and still someone downvoted....baaaaa)

Comment: @all so you mean this is a limitation? yeah?